# Putting a Python Interpreter in a Beamer Slide

Tags: python, python-idle, beamer

Is there anyway to put a Python Interpreter (like Idle) in a Beamer Slide? I wanted to live code some things, and it would be easier to do it if I could just code inside the slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, because there is no option to include a Shell or other programm inside a PDF document.

However, you could try to find a Python interpreter that is based on Javascript and include as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219807/using-javascript-inside-a-pdf).