# JavaScript inserted in PDF does not work

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

My goal is to open a PDF in a new browser tab and to fire JavaScript. I have two problems:

- The PDF does not get displayed in Firefox. I see the PDF viewer elements, but no page is displayed and I get the message that the PDF cannot get rendered correctly.
- In Chrome, the PDF gets displayed. However, the JavaScript does not fire.

Here comes my code:

```
 $file = file_get_contents('http://bililite.com/blog/blogfiles/pdf/preschool%20physical-fields.pdf');
 $js = <<<EOT
/Names << /JavaScript <</Names [ (EmbeddedJS) <<
    alert('test');
) >> ]  >> >>
EOT;

$file =  preg_replace(
            '#/Type\s*/Catalog#',
            '$0'.$js,
            $file
        );
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
echo $file;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript inside a PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219807/using-javascript-inside-a-pdf)

Comment: @Max Is it directly download on firefox ..?

Comment: No, there is no download, which is not my goal anyway.

Comment: Your attempt to inject the Javascript into the PDF effectively damages it: The final cross reference section becomes incorrect. Furthermore the piece you do insert may cause trouble if there already is a **Names** entry in the catalog as their shall be only one. Last but not least the piece you inject is syntactically incorrect, in particular the `<<
    alert('test');
) >>` part makes no sense.

Comment: @mkl Thank you. Do you see any way to get this working?

Comment: My goal is that the pdf when it is opened in a new tab gets automatically printed and the browser print overlay shows up.

Comment: *Do you see any way to get this working?* - Whenever you try to manipulate a PDF, do use a PDF library. I don't know which PDF libraries there are for PHP, but trying to patch something into PDFs without something like that is asking for trouble.