# hide header div when table has no rows using css

Tags: html, css

How can I hide the header div when there are no rows in the table. My css is not working.

```css
.myTable:empty ~ .header {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="header">ADDITIONAL ITEMS:</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="table-responsive m-t">
    <table class="myTable">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions, Please!

Comment: There is no parent selector in `CSS`, you need to use `JS`

Comment: But jquery is not working in my PDF view. that's why I m trying to do like this

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219807/using-javascript-inside-a-pdf)?

Comment: Okay,thank you will check the link

Comment: you can hide the whole table with  

            table:has(>tbody:empty)  {
              display:none;
            }

Answer (score 1):

Updated Snippet :

```js
if($(".myTable tr").length > 0){
 alert('row present')
}else{
 $('.header').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="header">ADDITIONAL ITEMS:</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="table-responsive m-t">
    <table class="myTable">
     <!--<tr></tr>-->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But jquery won't work in my PDF view :(

Answer (score 0):

> You can not use pure css,you **in css can not** first check childrens of table,if table have children(in here `tr`) show `.header` else hide `.header`,because css have not backward.you must use jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(!$('.myTable').find('tr').length) 
    $('.header').hide();
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(!$('.myTable').find('tr').length) 
    $('.header').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="header">ADDITIONAL ITEMS:</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="table-responsive m-t">
    <table class="myTable">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But jquery won't work in my PDF view :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a previous element because CSS does not work backwards (Hence, `Cascading` Style Sheet)

BUT, If you really want to use only CSS, you can use flex:

https://jsfiddle.net/0d7402sm/

```
#flex { 
  display: flex; 
  /* Optional, if you want the DIVs 100% width: */ 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myTable:empty ~ .header {
  display:none;
}

#flex > .myTable { order: 2; }
#flex > .header { order: 1; }
```