# Does pdf.js execute javascript contained in a pdf file?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

It appears that PDF has, for lack of a better term the ["feature" to contain javascript](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=6622), but luckily it seems there is a change that [only some software implements support for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219807/using-javascript-inside-a-pdf)

Since web browsers deal already with the issue to handle tons of  untrusted input, and hence do some sort of sandboxing, I rather appreciate to open pdf documents inside the browser sandbox via `pdf.js`. However I wonder if `pdf.js` will implement the "javascript contained in pdf file misfeature"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdf.js still does not support embedded javascript

There are some other implementations (e.g. https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/pdf-forms) but most of them have some limitations unless you are looking for simple field/form calculations

Comment: "still not" sounds like it targets support at a later state? Is my hope that Javascript in PDF will be something that will not become mainstream just wishfull thinking?

Comment: Given that most of original Mozilla pdf.js team is gone and the recent activity this is very likely not going to happen anytime soon :(

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1100769

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2022**: Since Summer 2021, pdf.js (and by extension, my library ngx-extended-pdf-viewer) uses [Quick.js](https://bellard.org/quickjs/quickjs.html) to run JavaScript in a sandbox. You've already mentioned that the browser runs JavaScript in a sandbox, so this is a sandbox running in a sandbox. The Mozilla team didn't want to give the JavaScript code embedded in the PDF file access to browser resources.

If you're using Firefox as a PDF viewer, you're using a slightly different version of pdf.js. It runs the JavaScript code in the same sandbox that runs Firefox WebExtensions.

Here's an article written by the authors of the JavaScript implementation: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2021/10/implementing-form-filling-and-accessibility-in-the-firefox-pdf-viewer/